# Operator()&, как специальная функция член

Tags: c++

В книге "Стивен Прата Язык программирования C++ Лекции и упражнения" прочел, что компилятор так же генерирует автоматически операцию взятия адреса у класса, если в коде где-то она используется.
[image: Скриншот из книги. Глава 12]

[image: оригинальная книга]
Я изучаю язык и больше нигде не встречал подобных высказываний. Действительно ли компилятор генерирует внутри класса конструкицю T* operator&(), или же она создается где-то во вне.

Я знаю, что ее можно переопределить и что начиная с какого-то стандарта вроде были наложены на это некоторые ограничения. Но чисто интуитивно мне казалось, что если не переопределена явно, операция взятия адреса ячейки памяти, в которой хранится объект, вызывает какую-то встроенную в ОС функцию.
Пытаюсь узнать подробнее, но не получается найти информацию.

Так же вопрос, если мы переопределили этот оператор, например, что бы узнать кол-во взятий адреса объекта, то как вернуть указатель на объект? Используя операцию взятия адреса? А рекурсия? - **UPD** снимается, просто **this** возращаем же и все

Просьба помочь объяснить эти моменты или поделиться ссылкой на rus/eng ресурс в интернете.
Спасибо!

Comment: Угу, в книге ошибка, `operator&` не создается автоматически внутри класса, он просто работает и все. И плюс непонятно, что ещё за деструктор "по умолчанию", и где про перемещающие операции (книга старая?).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, книга старая по c++11. Отрывок только из главы про знакомство с классами, про семантику перемещения только к концу книги рассказывается. Про деструктор по-умолчанию, он же тоже генерится, разве нет? Можно даже ~SomeClass() = default; написать

Comment: И даже ~SomeClass() = delete
https://www.rangakrish.com/index.php/2020/03/04/deleted-destructor-in-c/

Comment: Неправильно говорить "деструктор по умолчанию". Рядом написано "конструктор по умолчанию" и "деструктор по умолчанию". Первое означает что конструктор можно вызвать без аргументов, а второе - так не говорят, потому что деструктор всегда без аргументов.

Comment: *"Неявная операция взятия адреса возвращает адрес вызывающего объекта (т.е.значение указателя this)."* Может быть автор имел в виду работу **this** - что она создаётся и передаётся автоматически?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat видимо тонкости перевода с английского. default destructor все же пишут иногда, имея ввиду тот, который генерируется по умолчанию

Comment: Неправильно пишут. Лучше в этом случае говорить что-то типа "implicitly generated" (или implicitly generated/defined).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну видимо все же пишут, или раньше писали)) Добавил в пост скриншот из оригинальной книги - "Stephen Prate c++ primer plus 6th edition". Деструктор - default. И по поводу address operator как будто бы тоже прямо operator& имелось ввиду. Надо будет на eng stackoverflow спросить будет еще

Comment: Так я ведь не говорю, что перевод кривой. Это оригинал кривой. Держите ссылки: 1. [Определение "default constructor"](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#1) (сводится к "можно вызвать с 0 аргументов") (там же про то, что автоматически создаваемый конструктор называется "implicitly declared as defaulted"), 2. По [предметному указателю](http://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex) можете убедиться, что термина "default destructor" нет. 3. Автоматически создаваемый деструктор тоже называется ["implicitly declared as defaulted"](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#2).

Comment: Сложно дать ссылку на отсутствие автоматической генерации `operator&()` (раз ее нет, то про нее ничего и не написано), но как минимум `operator&` нет в списке [специальных членов класса](http://eel.is/c++draft/special#1).

Comment: Очень странный этот Стивен. Если он про оператор `&` говорит, то почему про `,` не упоминает? Её тоже можно перегрузить.